# Not able to login the application with csv?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using jmeter & configure the csv file for the multiple user login but noy able to login the application with the valid credentials,always displaying the alert message "Please enter the valid credentials".

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the csv data set, be sure there are no spaces between the comma and variable names in the Variable Names (comma-delimited) line.

```
Variable Names (comma-delimited): USER_NAME, PASS
```

will not work.

```
Variable Names (comma-delimited): USER_NAME,PASS
```

will.